# How to create an interface with readline

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, readline

I want to create a communication between two clients using the matrix server, and the sdk and readline packages.

How do I create a customer:

```
var myUserId = "@nina:my.domain.name";
var myAccessToken = "nina";
var sdk = require("matrix-js-sdk");
var clc = require("cli-color");
var matrixClient = sdk.createClient({
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:8448",
  idBaseUrl: "https://vector.im",
  accessToken: myAccessToken,
  userId: myUserId
});
```

And when I create an interface:

```
var readline = require("readline");
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  completer: completer
});
rl.setPrompt("$ ");
```

I get this error :
`ERROR TypeError: readline.createInterface is not a function`

Comment: you can use prompt in javascript

Comment: @sumeetkumar
I'm not sure I understand what you say .. I need to use prompt instead what ?